# How to retrieve child from Firebase Database with a randomkey into recycler view in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm actually new to Android programming, but I want to retrieve a child (comment) from Firebase Database with a random key into RecyclerView. I've written some code but when I launch the application the child (comment) does not show it does not also give me any error. Please help, thanks in advance.

[image: My firebase database image]

My Java Code:

```
private String commentsID = "";
private ImageView imageView, share, commentimage, profileimage, newslikeimage, send;
private TextView heading, description, newsdate, newstime, newscounter, sharecounter, newcommentcounter, profilename;
private String commentsend, commentcurrentusers, newcommentcurrentusers;
private EditText writecomment;
private DatabaseReference commentRef;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private String saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime, commentRandomKey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);

    commentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments");
    
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.commentrecycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    commentsID = getIntent().getStringExtra("comments");

    imageView = findViewById(R.id. newsimage);
    heading = findViewById(R.id. newsname);
    description = findViewById(R.id. newsdescription);
    newsdate = findViewById(R.id. newdate);
    newstime = findViewById(R.id. newtime);
    newscounter = findViewById(R.id. newcounter);
    sharecounter = findViewById(R.id. sharecounter);
    commentimage = findViewById(R.id. commentimage);
    newcommentcounter = findViewById(R.id. newcommentcounter);

    newslikeimage = findViewById(R.id. newslike);
    share = findViewById(R.id. share);
    profileimage = findViewById(R.id. profileimage);
    profilename = findViewById(R.id. profilename);
    send = findViewById(R.id. send);
    writecomment = findViewById(R.id. sendcomment);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    newcommentcurrentusers = currentuser.getUid();

    getCommentsDetails(commentsID);


    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            commentsend = writecomment.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(commentsend))
            {
                Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "Please type your comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                sendingCommentsToFirebase();
            }

        }
    });

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Comment> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comment>()
                    .setQuery(commentRef, Comment.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentsViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentsViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Comment model) {

                    holder.comment.setText(model.getComments());
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public CommentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_item_layout, parent, false);
                    CommentsViewHolder holder = new CommentsViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }
            };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

private void sendingCommentsToFirebase()
{
    FirebaseUser currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    commentcurrentusers = currentuser.getUid();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calendar.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

    commentRandomKey = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;

    HashMap<String, Object> commentMap = new HashMap<>();
    commentMap.put("comments", commentsend);
    commentMap.put("userID", commentcurrentusers);
    commentMap.put("newspid", commentRandomKey);

    commentRef.child(commentsID).push().setValue(commentMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<Void> task)
        {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "Comments added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}

private void getCommentsDetails(String commentsID) {
    DatabaseReference newsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News");

    newsRef.child(commentsID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                News news = snapshot.getValue(News.class);

                heading.setText(news.getHeading());
                description.setText(news.getDecription());
                profilename.setText(news.getUsername());
                newsdate.setText(news.getDate());
                newstime.setText(news.getTime());
                newscounter.setText(news.getLikes());
                sharecounter.setText(news.getShare());
                newcommentcounter.setText(news.getComment());

                Picasso.get().load(news.getProfileimage()).into(profileimage);
                Picasso.get().load(news.getImage()).into(imageView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

This is my View Holder

```
public class CommentActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private String commentsID = "";
    private ImageView imageView, share, commentimage, profileimage, newslikeimage, send;
    private TextView heading, description, newsdate, newstime, newscounter, sharecounter, newcommentcounter, profilename;
    private String commentsend, commentcurrentusers, newcommentcurrentusers;
    private EditText writecomment;
    private DatabaseReference commentRef;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private String saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime, commentRandomKey;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);

        commentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments");
        
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.commentrecycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        commentsID = getIntent().getStringExtra("comments");

        imageView = findViewById(R.id. newsimage);
        heading = findViewById(R.id. newsname);
        description = findViewById(R.id. newsdescription);
        newsdate = findViewById(R.id. newdate);
        newstime = findViewById(R.id. newtime);
        newscounter = findViewById(R.id. newcounter);
        sharecounter = findViewById(R.id. sharecounter);
        commentimage = findViewById(R.id. commentimage);
        newcommentcounter = findViewById(R.id. newcommentcounter);

        newslikeimage = findViewById(R.id. newslike);
        share = findViewById(R.id. share);
        profileimage = findViewById(R.id. profileimage);
        profilename = findViewById(R.id. profilename);
        send = findViewById(R.id. send);
        writecomment = findViewById(R.id. sendcomment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        newcommentcurrentusers = currentuser.getUid();

        getCommentsDetails(commentsID);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                commentsend = writecomment.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(commentsend))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "Please type your comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    sendingCommentsToFirebase();
                }

            }
        });

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Comment> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comment>()
                        .setQuery(commentRef, Comment.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentsViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Comment model) {

                        holder.comment.setText(model.getComments());
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public CommentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_item_layout, parent, false);
                        CommentsViewHolder holder = new CommentsViewHolder(view);
                        return holder;
                    }
                };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    private void sendingCommentsToFirebase()
    {
        FirebaseUser currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        commentcurrentusers = currentuser.getUid();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calendar.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

        commentRandomKey = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;

        HashMap<String, Object> commentMap = new HashMap<>();
        commentMap.put("comments", commentsend);
        commentMap.put("userID", commentcurrentusers);
        commentMap.put("newspid", commentRandomKey);

        commentRef.child(commentsID).push().setValue(commentMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<Void> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "Comments added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void getCommentsDetails(String commentsID) {
        DatabaseReference newsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News");

        newsRef.child(commentsID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    News news = snapshot.getValue(News.class);

                    heading.setText(news.getHeading());
                    description.setText(news.getDecription());
                    profilename.setText(news.getUsername());
                    newsdate.setText(news.getDate());
                    newstime.setText(news.getTime());
                    newscounter.setText(news.getLikes());
                    sharecounter.setText(news.getShare());
                    newcommentcounter.setText(news.getComment());

                    Picasso.get().load(news.getProfileimage()).into(profileimage);
                    Picasso.get().load(news.getImage()).into(imageView);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my Class:

```
public class Comment
{
    private String comments, newspid, userID;

    private Comment()
    {

    }

    public Comment(String comments, String newspid, String userID) {
        this.comments = comments;
        this.newspid = newspid;
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String getNewspid() {
        return newspid;
    }

    public void setNewspid(String newspid) {
        this.newspid = newspid;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you aren't getting anything in your RecyclerView because of the following reference:

```
commentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments");
```

Under your "Comments" node there are no objects of type "Comment", there are only keys that strings (Sept 03, 2021...). To be able to read the objects you are interested in, you should remove that extra level in your database, as it's not needed since I see that you are already storing the "date" into the `newspid` property. So your schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Comments
        |
        --- $commentId
               |
               --- comments: "This is my comment"
               |
               --- newspid: "Sept 06..."
               |
               --- userID: "D31D..."
```

And your code can remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Alex has the gist of the problem in his answer: the adapters in FirebaseUI can only show a flat list of nodes from your database, while you have two nested levels.

You can either do as Alex suggested, and store all comments in a flat list, or you can show the comments for one specific day from your current data structure with:

```
commentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                             .child("Comments").child("Sep 03, 202100:21:52 AM");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will do that.